# Web.Config Transform Individual AppSettings to ConfigSource

Tags: asp.net, xslt, web-config, web.config-transform

I'd like to transform the `appsettings` section of my local web.config file from a bunch of individual settings for my local dev work, to a `configSource` file path attribute for publishing to client servers.

Basically from this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="setting1" value="devVal1"></add> 
    <add key="setting2" value="devVal2"></add>
    <add key="setting3" value="devVal3"></add>
</appSettings>
```

to this:

```
<appSettings configSource="clientSettings.config" />
```

---

This partial solution adds the configSource attribute.

```
<appSettings xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(configSource)" configSource="clientSettings.config"/>
```

But I'm not sure how to remove all the individual settings as well (*I think the configSource will override them anyway, but I'd prefer to not have them there at all, to avoid having irrelevant dev settings in each of my client's web.config files*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit more perseverance lead me to the answer. Apply the "RemoveAll" transform to an `add` element within the `appSetting`.

```
<appSettings xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(configSource)" configSource="clientSettings.config">
    <add xdt:Transform="RemoveAll"/>
</appSetting>
```

Hope this is of use to someone in the future (*if only as an example of why you should do 30 minutes of extra work before reaching for the 'Ask Question' button*)...